# Adding operator support to interfaces (Preview Feature in .NET 6)

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, .net-7.0, c#-11.0, .net-generic-math

Just a warning, this question requires a preview of .NET 6 to be installed

---

I'm trying to create an interface in C# that can allow the `+` operator similar to how it is implemented in Microsoft's [`INumber<T>`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/INumber.cs).

**Interfaces.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Versioning;

namespace InterfaceTest;

[RequiresPreviewFeatures]
public interface IExtendedArray<T> : IAdditionOperators<IExtendedArray<T>, IExtendedArray<T>, IExtendedArray<T>>
    where T : INumber<T>
{
    Array Data { get; }
}

[RequiresPreviewFeatures]
public interface IExtendedFloatingPointArray<T> : IExtendedArray<T>
    where T : IFloatingPoint<T>
{

}
```

**InterfaceTest.csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <EnablePreviewFeatures>true</EnablePreviewFeatures>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>false</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.Experimental" Version="6.0.0-preview.7.21377.19" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

However, this code produces

> error CS8920: The interface 'InterfaceTest.IExtendedArray' cannot be used as type parameter 'TSelf' in the generic type or method 'IAdditionOperators<TSelf, TOther, TResult>'. The constraint interface 'System.IAdditionOperators<InterfaceTest.IExtendedArray, InterfaceTest.IExtendedArray, InterfaceTest.IExtendedArray>' or its base interface has static abstract members.

Is there a way achieve this with custom types?

---

`dotnet --list-sdks` shows I have `6.0.100-rc.1.21458.32` installed. But I just had it installed through the Visual Studio 2022 Preview 4.

Comment: Compiles for me fine with rc version of .NET 6.

Comment: It is a [.NET 7 preview feature](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-6-preview-7/), add `<EnablePreviewFeatures>True</EnablePreviewFeatures>` to the project file.

Comment: @GuruStron That's annoying. I updated the question to include more info about my specific dotnet version. It's also an RC, but don't know if it is the same as yours?

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for that. I had already included that, but forgot to put it in the question. I have updated my question to include the csproj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I was able to reproduce your issue - needed to install VS 2022 preview (2019 version compiled code just fine but failed in the runtime) or use `dotnet build` from terminal.

If you want to do something similar with `INumber` you need to follow the same pattern with `TSelf` type reference (if I'm not mistaken it is called [curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)):

```cs
[RequiresPreviewFeatures]
public interface IExtendedArray<TSelf, T> : IAdditionOperators<TSelf, TSelf, TSelf> where TSelf : IExtendedArray<TSelf, T> where T : INumber<T>
{
    T[] Data { get; }
}


[RequiresPreviewFeatures]
public interface IExtendedFloatingPointArray<TSelf, T> : IExtendedArray<TSelf, T>
    where TSelf : IExtendedFloatingPointArray<TSelf, T>
    where T : IFloatingPoint<T>
{

}
```