# How can I use IAdditionOperators<,,> from .NET 6 preview 7?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0, preview-feature, .net-generic-math

I have installed .NET 6 Preview 7 successfully. I have access to `System.IAdditionOperators<,,>`. My problem is that when I try to implement the interface it doesn't require me to define the `+` operator.

My project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <EnablePreviewFeatures>true</EnablePreviewFeatures>
    <LangVersion>preview</LangVersion>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.Experimental" Version="6.0.0-preview.7.21377.19" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

My one and only class:

```
using System;

namespace TestCode
{
    public class Foo:IAdditionOperators<Foo,Foo,Foo>
    {
    }
}
```

The code compiles (which it shouldn't!) even though I haven't implemented `IAdditionOperators<Foo,Foo,Foo>`. How do I make it force me to implement the `+` operator?

I have already downloaded the SDK, and updated Visual Studio to version 16.11.4. I have already checked the box for "Use preview of the .NET SDK" and restarted Visual Studio. What else do I have to do?

Comment: According to the [source](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IAdditionOperators.cs), these are `static` operators, so I would imagine the usual implementation constraints don't apply.  You could file a feature request/bug report.

Comment: You can find a related discussion from 2008 about `abstract` `static` interface members [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3284/102937).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the compilation fail you need either to use `dotnet build` from terminal or install VS 2022 Preview (I had the same problem for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69238213/adding-operator-support-to-interfaces-preview-feature-in-net-6/69243567#69243567)). As for the code compiled by VS 2019 - it
should fail in runtime when you try to start your application.